# Wrong value on the X axis of an LSM303 accelerometer

Tags: arduino, accelerometer, atmega328p

I am currently developing a library for the [LSM303](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Magneto/LSM303%20Datasheet.pdf) and I have an issue reading the X axis, I have the right values on the other two axes (Y, Z), I'm using I²C bus on an Atmega328P.

My reading: **X: 39.39 Y: 0.12 Z: 8.63 m/s^2**

Arduino LSM303 library reading : **X: -0.46  Y: 0.00  Z: 8.13 m/s^2**

I've configured the LSM303 in +-2g, high resolution, normal mode (1.344 kHz) / Low-power mode off / X-Y-Z on

[image]

[image]

[image]

Once the sensor is configured, I read the values in two components and I bit-shift the values in order to obtain an `int` value.

Finnaly, I convert those values by multiplying by sensivity and earth gravity.

Here is the code:

```
void LSM303_Init()
{
    i2c_init();
    
    i2c_start_wait(LSM303_ACC_WRITE_ADDRESS);
    i2c_write(ACCEL_CTRL_REG1_A);
    i2c_write(0x97);//Configuration :  Normal (1.344 kHz) / Low-power mode off / X-Y-Z on
    i2c_stop();

    i2c_start_wait(LSM303_ACC_WRITE_ADDRESS);
    i2c_write(ACCEL_CTRL_REG4_A);
    i2c_write(0x88);
    i2c_stop();

}

uint16_t LSM303_GetRawXAcc()
{
    uint8_t xlo = 0;
    uint8_t xhi = 0;
    uint16_t rawAccX = 0;
    
    i2c_start_wait(LSM303_ACC_WRITE_ADDRESS);
    i2c_write(ACCEL_OUT_X_L_A);
    i2c_rep_start(LSM303_ACC_READ_ADDRESS);
    xlo = i2c_readNak();
    
    i2c_start_wait(LSM303_ACC_WRITE_ADDRESS);
    i2c_write(ACCEL_OUT_X_H_A);
    i2c_rep_start(LSM303_ACC_READ_ADDRESS);
    xhi = i2c_readNak();
    
    i2c_stop();
    
    rawAccX = (int16_t)(xlo | (xhi << 8));
    
    return rawAccX;
}

uint16_t LSM303_GetRawYAcc()
{
    uint8_t ylo = 0;
    uint8_t yhi = 0;
    uint16_t rawAccY = 0;
    
    i2c_start_wait(LSM303_ACC_WRITE_ADDRESS);
    i2c_write(ACCEL_OUT_Y_L_A);
    i2c_rep_start(LSM303_ACC_READ_ADDRESS);
    ylo = i2c_readNak();
    
    i2c_start_wait(LSM303_ACC_WRITE_ADDRESS);
    i2c_write(ACCEL_OUT_Y_H_A);
    i2c_rep_start(LSM303_ACC_READ_ADDRESS);
    yhi = i2c_readNak();
    
    i2c_stop();
    
    rawAccY = (int16_t)(ylo | (yhi << 8));
    
    return rawAccY;
}

uint16_t LSM303_GetRawZAcc()
{
    uint8_t zlo = 0;
    uint8_t zhi = 0;
    uint16_t rawAccZ = 0;
    
    i2c_start_wait(LSM303_ACC_WRITE_ADDRESS);
    i2c_write(ACCEL_OUT_Z_L_A);
    i2c_rep_start(LSM303_ACC_READ_ADDRESS);
    zlo = i2c_readNak();
    
    i2c_start_wait(LSM303_ACC_WRITE_ADDRESS);
    i2c_write(ACCEL_OUT_Z_H_A);
    i2c_rep_start(LSM303_ACC_READ_ADDRESS);
    zhi = i2c_readNak();
    
    i2c_stop();
    
    rawAccZ = (int16_t)(zlo | (zhi << 8));
    
    return rawAccZ;
}

float LSM303_GetXAcc()
{
    //return ((LSM303_GetRawXAcc() * 0.061) * 0.01);
    return (LSM303_GetRawXAcc() >> 4) * 0.00098 * 9.81;
}

float LSM303_GetYAcc()
{
    return (LSM303_GetRawYAcc() >> 4) * 0.00098 * 9.81;
}

float LSM303_GetZAcc()
{
    return (LSM303_GetRawZAcc() >> 4) * 0.00098 * 9.81;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: Nothing wrong with data sheet extracts but, you should supply a link to that data sheet. Also, you should ask an actual question.

Comment: Your `(LSM303_GetRawXAcc() >> 4)` does not preserve the sign bit in your raw value - you're turning a small negative value into a large positive one. You've committed the 'sin' of premature optimization and thinking you're smarter than the compiler ;) Just do `/ 16` and let the compiler optimize it for you.

Comment: Thank you I will try